# haproxy two applications on the same port with different certificates

Tags: networking, reverse-proxy, https, haproxy

I am setting up haproxy.
My config is:

```
frontend bothApps
        bind *:9999
        mode http
        acl prov path_end -i /prov-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/
        acl web path end -i /web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/
        acl prov1 path_end -i /prov-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/testAuthenticated.html
        acl web1 path_end -i /web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/testAuthenticated.html
        use_backend focus if prov
        use_backend focus if prov1
        use_backend cnt if web
        use_backend cnt if web1
```

and it works correctly without https. Now I would like to add https but both apps should call haproxy on port `8443` (`https://localhost:8443/prov-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` and `https://localhost:8443/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`) but with different certificates - prov(`haproxyPROV.pem`), web(`haproxyWEB.pem`). How can I configure it?

I tried:

```
frontend https
        bind *:8443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/haproxyWEB.pem
        mode http
```

but here I can just have one certificate per port

Comment: Just use one certificate.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I can't use one certificate, I know that would be easy but it is not the case here - I need both certs

Comment: Eh? Why do you have two certificates for the same subject? Did you omit important details? If so, edit your question.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, clients wish, they want two certificates on reverse proxy shooting to another apps on tomcat.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to have two certificates for localhost:8443. What is really going on here?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, in real life it won't be localhost of course. There is server which should accept both /web and /prov on the same port with different certificates. Is it even doable in haproxy?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to have two certificates for _any_ name, whether localhost or something else. Haproxy is irrelevant. It is not possible to know which certificate to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use more than once certificate on one port:

```
frontend foo
    bind *:8443 ssl crt /path/to/cert1.pem crt /path/to/cert2.pem
```

Haproxy uses TLS SNI to match certificate to connection (if SNI is not present or not match is found, then first certificate on `bind` line is used (cert1.pem in above example)). So to achieve your goal you would have to point two different domain names to this host:port. Like `web.example.com` and `prov.example.com` pointing to the same host. That's what all those comments are about i guess.
Side note, you use `path_end` in your ACLs, like `acl prov path_end -i /prov-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/`, but that will match also `/foobar/prov-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/` and `/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/prov-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/`, which may or may not be what you want. Usually `path` or `path_beg` are more fitting.

Comment: Thank you, @tbielaszewski! However I used @MichaelHampton suggestion and used two frontends with different ports calling the same backend: `frontend web_https  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/haproxyWEB.pem  use_backend duo    frontend prov_https  bind *:9999 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/haproxyPROV.pem  use_backend duo`


but it means that when I have only localhost, I still can't use two certificates on one port, right?

Comment: Different ports or differents hostnames (SNI). Tertium non datur.